OpenSearch is not working after provide SSL certificates
Version (relevant - OpenSearch/Dashboard/Server OS/Browser):
OpenSearch -> 2.16.0
Dashboard   -> 2.3.0
Issue:
OpenSearch cluster is not working after swtich from opensearch self-generated certificates to SSL certificates.
It was working perfectly fine using the default opensearch self-generated certificates, with the demo files and http enable for transport nodes. The issue started once I created my own ssl certificates and remove the http part from the transport nodes.
I've been following the documentation from (https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-k8s-operator/blob/main/docs/userguide/main.md), I've created my own ssl certificates following the documentation from (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/configuration/generate-certificates/).
I've created my own tls secrets using ssl certificates (one for admin and one for all the transport nodes), also my own admin-secret for a custom username and password and security config secret, including all the files from this url (https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/tree/main/config) but updating the admin hash with the new password.
One thing I noticed is that even though I provided the custom adminsecret, opensearch is creating a new one (but with the same values I provided).
The security pod is returning an error stating that "Waiting to connect to the cluster" as the screenshot below
I'm multiple errors from all nodes, as the ones below:
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-09-25T21:14:21Z","tags":["warning","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to connect to OpenSearch. Error: Given the configuration, the ConnectionPool was not able to find a usable Connection for this request."}

{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-09-25T21:18:08Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: write EPROTO 139884884653952:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:\n"}

[2024-09-25T21:46:39,346][ERROR][o.o.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] [opensearch-bootstrap-0] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)

[2024-09-25T21:46:19,167][ERROR][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-bootstrap-0] Failed loading builtin log types from disk!

[2024-09-25T21:47:07,816][ERROR][o.o.s.t.SecurityRequestHandler] [opensearch-bootstrap-0] OpenSearchException[Transport client authentication no longer supported.]

[2024-09-25T21:46:20,958][ERROR][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch-bootstrap-0] Failure no such index [.opendistro_security] retrieving configuration for [ACTIONGROUPS, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT, CONFIG, INTERNALUSERS, NODESDN, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, WHITELIST] (index=.opendistro_security)

Configuration:
  security:
    config:                   # Everything related to the securityconfig
      securityConfigSecret:
        name: securityconfigsecret.name               # Name of the secret that contains the securityconfig files
      adminSecret:
        name: adminsecret.name
      adminCredentialsSecret:
        name: admincredentialssecret.name
    tls:                     # Everything related to TLS configuration
      transport:             # Configuration of the transport endpoint
        generate: false      # Have the operator generate and sign certificates
        perNode: false       # Separate certificate per node
        secret:
          name: secret.name             # Name of the secret that contains the provided certificate
        caSecret:
          name: casecret.name            # Name of the secret that contains a CA the operator should use.
        nodesDn: [CN=node.other.com,OU=SSL,O=Test,L=Test,C=DE,OU=TEST,O=TEST,C=US]         # List of certificate DNs allowed to connect
        adminDn: [CN=admin,OU=SSL,O=Test,L=Test,C=DE,OU=TEST,O=TEST,C=US]         # List of certificate DNs that should get admin access
  



Had the same issue, looks like this is related to the existing demo config that overrode main config parameters:
https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/pull/4793
The fix was added to the version 2.18.0
